# Shelving Pending Changes in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, version-control, tfvc

Right now I have some major code changes that won't be done in time for an upcoming release and need to be shelved.  Is there a good way to get these changes out of my workspace but be able to return to them later?  Maybe I am missing something, but looks like the changes remain in the workspace even when they are shelved.

Is there a better way to do this?  I'd prefer not to create another workspace.

We're using VS 2008 and TFS 2008.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

When you shelve the changes, there is a checkbox towards the bottom "Preserve pending changes locally".  Uncheck that and it will undo the checkouts on the files as it builds the Shelf.

Also, once a shelf is created you can safely undo the checkouts yourself; Same result but I consider the checkbox a little safer in that it only undoes the checkout on files that you are shelving (so you won't accidentally undo the checkout of a file that you missed or intentionally didn't shelve).

Comment: Does this method pass the shelveset on to TFS for me to retrieve later?

Comment: Shelves are stored on the TFS server, so anything that creates a shelf should be retrievable later; You can always check your current Shelvesets before undoing your checkout (just hit "Unshelve" for a list of your shelvesets).